# slideUp not working after slideDown

Tags: jquery, slideup

slideUp not working after slideDown using jQuery 1.10.
Here's a fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8myee8k5/2/)

The HTML consists of "health-grid-header" li with a corresponding "health-grid-content" and between them a connecting line.

```html
<ul id="health-grid">
    <li class="health-grid-header">
        <div id="health-header-1">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="health-grid-container">
    <div id="health-line"></div>
    <div id="health-grid-1" class="health-grid-content">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum<span class="yellow-close-icon"></span>

        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

First, I hide the line and the content. Then, when header is clicked I use slideDown to animate and show the content and the line.

```js
var healthGridShowed = false;
$('.health-grid-content, #health-line').hide();
$('.health-grid-header').click(function () {
    // first check if the content is visible //
    if (healthGridShowed) {

    } else {
        // if not visible //
        var newContentIdNum = $(this).children().first().attr('id').slice(-1);
        var lineHalfWidth = $('#health-line').outerWidth();
        var headerPosition = $(this).position();
        var headerHalfWidth = $(this).width() / 2;
        $('#health-line').css({
            left: (headerHalfWidth + headerPosition.left - lineHalfWidth)
        });
        $('#health-line').slideDown(500);
        $('#health-grid-' + newContentIdNum).slideDown(500).delay(500, function () {
            $('#health-grid-' + newContentIdNum).addClass('health-active');
        });
    }
});
```

The content holds a small x on top right for collapsing the expandable section. Once pressed, should collapse it by using slideUp. Nothing happens though.

```js
$('.yellow-close-icon').click(function () {
    $('.health-active').slideUp(500, function () {
        $('#health-line').slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

If I only try sliding up the line it does happen but not the content.

Thanks

Comment: why not use slideToggle?
http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: slideToggle does the same thing...only when hidden it slides it down but not up (after the slideDown reveals it)

Comment: This is not good?

http://jsfiddle.net/gc067ytw/4/

Comment: Thanks @ZivWeissman but there were more factors into it like I didn't want the header to be clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you were adding the `class` `health-active`, I changed it to

```
$('#health-grid-' + newContentIdNum).addClass('health-active').slideDown(500);
```

Or you can also write it like

```
$('#health-grid-' + newContentIdNum).slideDown(500, function(){
$(this).addClass('health-active');
});
```

If you want to `addClass` after `fadeOut()` Completes.

And it is working. You were unnecesarily using `.delay`

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8myee8k5/5/)**

Comment: why in the world the '.delay' was messing this up? Thanks! That solved it